# WPF Custom MessageBox with Treeview and Text

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, forms, treeview

I like to have a custom [**message-box**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.messagebox?view=netcore-3.1) like this-

[image]

what I have done is-

```
// Configure the message box to be displayed
string messageBoxText = "Do you want to save changes?";
string caption = "Word Processor";
MessageBoxButton button = MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel;
MessageBoxImage icon = MessageBoxImage.Warning;

// Display message box
MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText, caption, button, icon);

// Display message box
MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText, caption, button, icon);

// Process message box results
switch (result)
{
    case MessageBoxResult.Yes:
        // User pressed Yes button
        // ...
        break;
    case MessageBoxResult.No:
        // User pressed No button
        // ...
        break;
    case MessageBoxResult.Cancel:
        // User pressed Cancel button
        // ...
        break;
}
```

In this case, I have the [MessageBoxResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.messageboxresult?view=netcore-3.1) button, but don't have the UI in the `message-box`. I am creating and calling the `message-box` from a non UI class.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: You realise a messagebox is actually a window? Build a window with 3 buttons and your treeview. Set dialogresult based on which button is pressed. And decouple that from your viewmodel to view. Use an eventaggregator or binding so the view showdialogs your window and your non ui class doesn't need to know about any ui.

Comment: You will have to create a custom view for that, as you cannot customize a message box like that...and even if you could, you should not.

Comment: [Custom dialog boxes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/dialog-boxes-overview#custom-dialog-boxes).